# Language student, car door - how do we pronounce them?

Tags: pronunciation

Rule for Normal Adjectives + Nouns:
The stress will usually fall on the noun, according to https://openoregon.pressbooks.pub/greentea/chapter/word-stress-compound-words-and-adj-noun-combinations/

When we use nouns as adjectives, do we follow the same rule? I assume the following are all normal noun + noun cases, not counpund words treated as one unit which often has a unique meaning.

**Example 1**
Computer gadget

**Example 2**
Room window

**Example 3**
Car door

**Example 4**
Language student

Comment: It's not really useful to think in terms of stress falling on the ***noun***. We stress the *most contextually **important*** word. So in *most* contexts you'd close *the car **window***, but if you were comparing the type of glass to that in your ***house** windows*, you'd draw a contrast with your ***car** windows*. In short, ***context is everything***, and there's no point in trying to classify specific collocations *without* a full context.

Comment: This is very similar to your previous question,  It would be good to add this detail to your previous question, instead of asking a new question.